# Escaping * character in java

Tags: java, string, escaping, special-characters

I am trying to execute the following operation on a String.

```
    if (combatLog.contains("//*name//*")) {
        combatLog.replaceAll("//*name//*",glad.target.name);
    }
```

The slashes are my attempt to escape the *, as it doesn't work without them. I have also tried one slash, and slashes on contains or replaceAll individually. Thanks

Comment: Use `backslashes` to escape.

Comment: Don't escape asterisks in `contains()`

Comment: Also, you need to re-assign the result of `replaceAll()` back to the string. Strings are immutable, and doesn't undergo in-place replacement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget about **immutability** of strings, and reassign the newly created string. Also, if your `if` block doesn't contain any more code, you don't need the `if` check at all.

You have 3 options:

```
if (combatLog.contains("*name*")) { // don't escape in contains()
    combatLog = combatLog.replaceAll("\\*name\\*", replacement);// correct escape
}
// another regex based solution
if (combatLog.contains("*name*")) {
    combatLog = combatLog.replaceAll("[*]name[*]", replacement);// character class
}
```

or without a regex

```
if (combatLog.contains("*name*")) {
    combatLog = combatLog.replace("*name*", replacement);// literal string
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`replaceAll()` (counter-intuitively) takes a regex, not a string.
To escape a character for a regex, you need a double-**back**slash (doubled to escape the backslash from the string literal).

However, you don't want a regex.  You should simply call `replace()` instead, which won't need any escaping.

Answer (score 5):

You're using forward slashes. The backslash is the escape character. Furthermore, unless the string is being used for regex or something similar, you need not escape the `*`, or the `/` if thats what you're trying to escape.

If combatLog is a String, its contains method checks for a sequence of characters only. If you're looking for `*name*` in the string, you only need call `combatLog.contains("*name*")`.

Answer (score 4):

You are using forward slashes use the backslash: `\` to escape characters

[edit]
also as slaks said you need to use `replace()` which accepts a string as input rather than a regex.